# Use rspec to test class methods are calling scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I have created rspec tests for my scopes (`scope1`, `scope2` and `scope3`) and they pass as expected but I would also like to add some tests for a class method that I have which is what is actually called from my controller (the controller calls the scopes indirectly via this class method):

```
def self.my_class_method(arg1, arg2)
  scoped = self.all

  if arg1.present?
    scoped = scoped.scope1(arg1)
  end

  if arg2.present?
    scoped = scoped.scope2(arg2)
  elsif arg1.present?
    scoped = scoped.scope3(arg1)
  end

  scoped
end
```

It seems a bit redundant to run the same scope tests for each scenario in this class method when I know they already pass so I assume I really only need to ensure that different scopes are called/applied dependant on the args being passed into this class method.

Can someone advise on what this rspec test would look like.

I thought it might be something along the lines of

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyModel.my_class_method(arg1, nil)).to receive(:scope1).with(arg1, nil)
```

but that doesn't work.

I would also appreciate confirmation that this is all that's necessary to test in this situation when I've already tested the scopes anyway would be reassurring.

Answer (score 0):

The Rspec code you wrote is really testing the internal implementation of your method. You should test that the method returns what you want it to return given the arguments, not that it does it in a certain way. That way, your tests will be less brittle. For example if you change what `scope1` is called, you won't have to rewrite your `my_class_method` tests.

I would do that by creating a number of instances of the class and then call the method with various arguments and check that the results are what you expect.

I don't know what `scope1` and `scope2` do, so I made an example where the arguments are a `name` attribute for you model and the scope methods simply retrieve all models except those with that name. Obviously, whatever your real arguments and `scope` methods do you should put that in your tests, and you should modify the expected results accordingly.

I used the `to_ary` method for the expected results since the `self.all` call actually returns an ActiveRecord association and therefore wouldn't otherwise match the expected array. You could probably use `includes` and `does_not_includes` instead of `eq`, but perhaps you care about the order or something.

```
describe MyModel do
  describe ".my_class_method" do
    # Could be helpful to use FactoryGirl here
    # Also note the bang (!) version of let
    let!(:my_model_1) { MyModel.create(name: "alex") }
    let!(:my_model_2) { MyModel.create(name: "bob") }
    let!(:my_model_3) { MyModel.create(name: "chris") }

    context "with nil arguments" do
      let(:arg1) { nil }
      let(:arg2) { nil }
      it "returns all" do
        expected = [my_model_1, my_model_2, my_model_3]
        expect_my_class_method_to_return expected
      end
    end

    context "with a first argument equal to a model's name" do
      let(:arg1) { my_model_1.name }
      let(:arg2) { nil }
      it "returns all except models with name matching the argument" do
        expected = [my_model_2, my_model_3]
        expect_my_class_method_to_return expected
      end

      context "with a second argument equal to another model's name" do
        let(:arg1) { my_model_1.name }
        let(:arg2) { my_model_2.name }
        it "returns all except models with name matching either argument" do
          expected = [my_model_3]
          expect_my_class_method_to_return expected
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def expect_my_class_method_to_return(expected)
    actual = described_class.my_class_method(arg1, arg2).to_ary
    expect(actual).to eq expected
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @rob-w. I was just wondering, if I have tests already for each of the scopes, should I change these to use `shared_examples`/`behaves_like` so that they can be re-used accordingly for this class method based on the args applied to the class method...if that makes sense?

Comment: @user1116573 Yes that makes sense and would result in very clean-looking test code. Just be aware that you will be tying the tests to the `scope1` and `scope2` methods.6 months from now if you or someone else changes what `scope1` does and fixes the `scope1` tests accordingly, the tests of `my_class_method` will pass also. That could be a good thing or a bad thing depending on the business logic.